# Angular Directive Children without transclude parent

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm working with Angular directives that looks like this:

```
<parent>
    <children></children>
    <children></children>
    <children></children>
</parent>
```

Parent directive has a

```
template: return "<div><ul></ul><div ng-transclude></div></div>"
```

And children directives will go inside that ng-transclude div.

My final HTML structure is

```
<newParent>
    <div ng-transclude>
        <child></child>
        <child></child>
        <child></child>
    </div>
</newParent>
```

I wonder if it's possible to remove that ng-transclude div so that the new children are direct children of the new parent. (I have more children, a random number >1).

I have to do so to match an existing template so I cannot change its structure.

I actually have no Fiddles, if you need more information just ask. Thank you!

Comment: can't you just use `<child ng-repeat>` in the parent template instead of the `transcludde` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can append the content yourself, without using `ng-transclude`, using the transclude function:

```
app.directive("parent", function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "EA",
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, $transclude) {

      $transclude(function(clone, scope) {
        element.append(clone);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Here's more information about [Transclusion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#transclusion).

Without a template, this will add the transcluded elements as only children of the directive. With the template, you'll need to properly place (e.g. insert it into a `<div>` after `<ul>`) the content yourself.